# Access UserControls from MenuStrip

Tags: c#

Im currently doing a car rental program and I'm having trouble opening some usercontrols by clicking on a menu strip. Made a few menustrips called UserControl1 and UserControl2. Already tried the code below but that doesn't work.

[Here is the Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7vy9.png)

```
private void customerRecordsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 f2 = new UserControl();
        f2.Show();
        
    }
```

Comment: **UserControls aren't forms/windows**. They only work as child controls of a parent `Form` object. So I'm curious what you expect `Show()` to do in this case exactly... And why aren't you using `Visible` instead? (You also need to add the user-control to the parent `Forms.Controls` collection (or rather: add it to an appropriate descendant container control, such as a `Panel` or `TabControl` first).

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't really be altering UI state directly from a menustrip click handler - that's how you get into state-management issues. You should consider looking at following a software **design pattern** for stateful UIs in desktop applications - there's a good number to choose from.